# Можно ли с помощью java скрипта визуально перемещать мышь на вебсайте, где будет установлен этот веб скрипт? Или это не реально?

Tags: javascript

Можно ли с помощью java скрипта визуально перемещать мышь на  вебсайте, где будет установлен этот веб скрипт?
Или это не реально?

на англоязычных комментарях пишут , что это невозможно?

You cannot move a mouse if that is what you're asking. But you could call a function with whatever context and arguments you want. E.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7772222/is-there-a-way-to-trigger-mousemove-and-get-event-pagex-event-pagey

Comment: Добавить некоторую активность на сайте. Иногда заходят на сайт люди или боты не понятно, и они не листают сайт, они висят на одной странице сайта, хочу что бы и от них была какая то польза, например при заходе на сайт , мышь дернулась, или автопрокрутка или клик по кнопке, это я почти все сделал,  все  работает, но все эта работа в java скрипте к сожалению браузером и счетчиками воспринимается как программные, я так понимаю, еще я так понял почему запретили управлять мышью, это считается вмешательством в управление и может восприниматься как вирус, поэтому мышкой визуально нельзя я так понимаю

Comment: это жесткий облом, я немного разачарован, а я думал в программирование нет пределов и запретов,

Comment: я думаю на каком нибудь другом языке может и возможно, но в основных браузерах их создатели пресекли возможность чувствовать себя " абсолютным Создателем" на java, может быть на каком нибудь питоне это и возможно,

Comment: @Bor java и javascript - вещи разные, "java скрипт" - неправильное название. Не стоит судить "программирование" по слухам только об одном языке, выучите парочку других и спокойно решайте все свои задачи. А еще "какой нибудь питон" прозвучало слегка неуважительно, уж простите, что об этом пишу - таки задело слегка.

Что касается вопроса - нет, средствами javascript нельзя перемещать курсор мыши, и слава за это его создателям, иначе была бы катастрофа.

Comment: что то мы походу пересекались где то? Задача не стоит случаем накрутка кликов с поисковика?